# Process synchronization techniques

Tags: c++, process, synchronization

For multi-threading, we can use synchronization primitives like `mutexes`, `semaphore`,
 `condition variables`.
How can I synchronize process instances?

For example, if I should not allow more than 1 instance of an application to run, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you just mean in general or in a specific language?

Comment: I am looking in C++ language

Comment: I think in that case, any of the threads on the right already have methods to help you. Marking as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [strict N process synchronization using 2 semaphores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266091/strict-n-process-synchronization-using-2-semaphores)

Comment: It does not have any proper answer

Comment: Oh, By my experences, for process sync, I have used socket communication. I suggest you use socket communication in your mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of named mutex or system level semaphore to detect if the instance of your application already exists and do not allow the second. additionally you may use single instance project property if you are building a vb.net app. refer to this post for C# implementation with mutex [Run single instance of an application using Mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819773/run-single-instance-of-an-application-using-mutex)